# How can I use libraries from DBFS instead of pre installed libraries in Databricks

Tags: python, databricks

I have this use case where I want to load python libraries from dbfs. I am not able to find a way  to override pre installed libraries in databricks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if I understood your problem, but you can install libraries in a cluster by opening the cluster configuration, and clicking on the Libraries tab. Then you can install new libraries, [like in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQpTy.png)

If it is an automated cluster, you can do this by adding an [init_script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) to install your libraries and override the pre installed ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but libraries installed through Libraries tab or init_scripts will be re-installed every time I terminate and start the cluster again. I don’t want this.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is a way to do what you want.